# Difficulty implementing handleOnPress function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement the `handleOnPress` function, the code is provided by the textbook which is confusing because it doesn't seem to be working as expected, in fact it does nothing.

The function is supposed to allow me to click the squares in the memory game, if the squares are the same color both of the chosen squares disappear, if you click on the same square twice the function resets and if you match two that aren't the same the function resets.

It would be really appreciated if anyone can take a look and point out any errors they see, thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Recipe: Drawing a square</title>
        <script src="easel.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvas;
            var stage;
            var squareSide = 70;
            var squareOutline = 5;
            var max_rgb_color_number = 255;
            var gray = createjs.Graphics.getRGB(20, 20, 20);
            var placementArray = [];
            var highlight = createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255, 255, 0);
            var tileClicked;

            function init() {
                var rows = 6;
                var columns = 6;
                var squarePadding = 10;
                canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

                var numberOfTiles = rows*columns;
                setPlacementArray(numberOfTiles);

                for(var i=0;i<numberOfTiles;i++){
                    var placement = getRandomPlacement(placementArray);
                    if(i % 2 === 0){
                        var color = randomColor();
                    }
                    square = drawSquare(color);
                    square.color = color;
                    square.x = (squareSide+squarePadding) * (placement%columns);
                    square.y = (squareSide+squarePadding) * Math.floor(placement/columns);
                    stage.addChild(square);
                    square.onPress = handleOnPress;
                    stage.update();
                }               
            }
            function drawSquare(color) {
                var shape = new createjs.Shape();
                var graphics = shape.graphics;
                graphics.setStrokeStyle(squareOutline);
                graphics.beginStroke(gray);
                graphics.beginFill(color);
                graphics.rect(squareOutline, squareOutline, squareSide, squareSide);                
                return shape;
            }       
            function randomColor(){
                var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*max_rgb_color_number);
                var color2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*max_rgb_color_number);
                var color3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*max_rgb_color_number);
                return createjs.Graphics.getRGB(color, color2, color3);
            }
            function setPlacementArray(numberOfTiles){
                for(var i=0;i<numberOfTiles;i++){
                    placementArray.push(i);
                }
            }
            function getRandomPlacement(placementArray){
                randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*placementArray.length);
                return placementArray.splice(randomNumber, 1)[0];
            }
            function handleOnPress(event){
                var tile = event.target;
                if(!!tileClicked === false){
                    tile.graphics.setStrokeStyle(squareOutline).beginStroke(highlight)
                      .rect(squareOutline, squareOutline, squareSide, squareSide);
                    tileClicked = tile;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(tileClicked.color === tile.color && tileClicked !== tile){
                        tileClicked.visible = false;
                        tile.visible = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        tileClicked.graphics.setStrokeStyle(squareOutline).beginStroke(gray)
                          .rect(squareOutline, squareOutline, squareSide, squareSide);
                    }
                        tileClicked = null;
                }
                stage.update();
            }   
        </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="960" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onEvent`-style handlers (onClick, onMouseDown, etc) were deprecated and removed a long time ago (Version 0.7.0, September 25, 2013).

Instead, use events, such as

```
square.addEventListener("mousedown", handleOnPress);
```

or the shortcut `on()` method:

```
square.on("mousedown", handleOnPress);
```

Note also there is no "press" event. There is a "mousedown" event, as well as "pressmove"/"pressup" events for drag and drop-style events.

Here is a listing of events on all display objects: https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#event_mousedown

I don't know if this will solve everything, but it should get your click handlers firing.

Comment: Thank you, I'm working with a book that is a bit outdated. Helped a ton!

Comment: No problem. There are some updated tutorials on the EaselJS website, as well as a decent set of demos, all of which use the latest syntax. https://easeljs.com